# creating own jQuery content slider / fade

Tags: jquery, slider

I don't want to use a plugin but am new to jQuery - I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="slide">
    <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="920" height="360" /></a>
    </div>

<div class="slide">
    <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="920" height="360" /></a>
    </div>

<div class="slide">
    <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="920" height="360" /></a>
    </div>
```

I have used jQuery to hide all but the first "slide" :

```
$('.slide:first').siblings().css('display', 'none');
```

What I now want to do is auto advance through the slide divs, so hide the first div.slide and show the second then hide that to show the third and repeat. I have looked at the fade toggle functions but am a bit lost?

Thanks, John

Comment: You're going to have a hard time telling when the slides are changing when they all have the same `src` attribute. Regardless, there are already lots of great explanations available for navigating through a slideshow. Here's one I found on the related tab to the right of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5317857/469643. You might be asking to bite off more than you could chew by rejecting plugins AND being new to jQuery. You could find a long road ahead of yourself.

Comment: Hi sorry thats an example the src attributes will be different for each one, I did see that link too but didnt find it helpful (maybe im too new?)

Comment: I would say that developing a rotating image carousel is probably not the first project I would have wanted to tackle using jQuery. There's a lot more that goes into it than what you probably suspect and what you're essentially asking for is a fully formed approach of which there are many out there and if you don't understand them then you probably wouldn't be able to understand an answer here; the [comments you got](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634078/creating-my-own-jquery-slider) on that question (2 hours ago) are still valid.

Comment: @veeTrain we don't know the skill level of the OP.  There is nothing wrong with starting with this project. It is actually a simple solution.  Also there the src attribute is irrelevant with regards to changing slides. You can do it via an index or which is visible.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you out a little bit. What it basically does is:

1. Hide all but first slide element.
2. In the function that is called you want to hide the currently shown element and show the next one.. It is quite simple:

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/CXsdP/4/

```
function doSlides() {

        var imgIndex = $('#slideshow div:visible').index();

        var imgNext = (imgIndex + 1) % $('#slideshow div').length;

        $('#slideshow div:visible').fadeOut(500);

        $('#slideshow div').eq(imgNext).fadeIn(500);
    }
    $('#slideshow div:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(doSlides, 1000);
```

Here is an alternate way to do it:

```
function doSlides() {
    var $imgIndex = $('#slideshow div:visible');

    var $next = $imgIndex.next();

    if ($next.length==0) {
        $next = $('#slideshow >:first-child');   // loop back to first 
    }
    $imgIndex.fadeOut(500);  
    $next.fadeIn(500);
}

$('#slideshow div:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(doSlides, 1000);
```

​
​

Comment: Nice solution and demonstration lucuma.